# Using categories vs parametrized tests from JUnit with selenium rc

Tags: selenium, junit, categories

I currently have a set of unit tests which are run with the Parametrized test harness built into JUnit.  As I do not want to create a new Selenium instance with each test case (i'd rather log in, navigate to a screen, and run a set of tests), I am looking at other options in which I can automate my tests.

I want to set up different tests in different classes which all leverage the same test method.I found the Categories also offered by JUnit however as this appears to be a way to set up a TestSuite, I am not sure if this will help.

I guess the short question is, if I have a bunch of selenium tests spread out to different classes is there a way I can get these tests to run in one test method specified elsewhere?

Comment: I would recommend you to switch to TestNG...

Answer (score 0):

You can create test suite in Junit over there you can write your different classes containing ur tests.
In Junit 4 a test suit is written like this.

```
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({TestClass1.class, TestClass2.class})
public class TestSuite {
//nothing
}
```